# My Sticky Header Cover Content with the Smooth Scrolling Effect

Tags: javascript, header, sticky, scroll-position

I added a sticky header and a smooth scrolling effect, and I cannot figure out how to fix the position so it counts with the header size. The things I have tried disable the sticky header completely.

I have tried to use several different techniques, although I am a newbie and it might be too hard for me to do by myself.

```
<div id="container">
  <section id="sectionHome">
    <!--Header and Logo-->
    <header id="myHeader">
      <logo>
        <img src="Pictures/Marvel-logo-880x660.crop.png">
      </logo>
    </header>

    <!--The Top Navigation Menu-->
    <div id="mainNav">
      <ul>
        <li class="current"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#firstArticle">Characters</a></li>
        <li><a href="#secondArticle">Movies</a></li>
        <li><a href="#thirdArticle">More Info</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </section>
```

```
//Smooth Scrolling in Main Nav
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#mainNav li a').click(function(e) {

    var targetHref = $(this).attr('href');

    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(targetHref).offset().top
    }, 1000);

    e.preventDefault();
  });
});


// Sticky Header
window.onscroll = function() {
  myFunction()
}; // When the user scrolls the page
var header = document.getElementById("sectionHome"); // Get the header and top nav
var sticky = header.offsetTop; // Get the offset position of the navbar
function myFunction() { // Add the sticky class to the header when you reach its scroll position. Remove "sticky" when you leave the scroll position
  if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
    header.classList.add("sticky");
  } else {
    header.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

This was one thing I tried, but it disabled my sticky header:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var headerHeight = $('header').outerHeight(); // Target your header navigation here

  $('#main-nav li a').click(function(e) {

    var targetHref   = $(this).attr('href');

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(targetHref).offset().top - headerHeight // Add it to the calculation here
    }, 1000);

    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

I thought I could set a value for the total header size and position it that way, although it disables the sticky header. How do I do this properly?

This is my webpage:
http://www.student.city.ac.uk/~aczc972

Best regards,
Danielle

Comment: Added another way to scroll to the top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added a sandbox how to do it using jQuery, generally speaking only one addition from my site is that I am checking what is the target e.g. scroll to top page, and if yes, I am running specified code for it:

```
if (targetHref === "#") {
  $("html, body").animate(
    { scrollTop: 0 },
    "1000"
  );
} else {
  $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: $(targetHref).offset().top},1000);
}
```

[codesandbox.io/s/81l87w26w0](https://codesandbox.io/s/81l87w26w0)

Subtract header height scroll to prevent covering content by header

```
scrollTop: $(targetHref).offset().top - 180"
```

Comment: So what happens when I add the code is that it disables the sticky header and my main slideshow of some reason. Your code works perfectly fine, although when added to mine the same thing happens. I wonder what I am missing here. 

This is the website: http://www.student.city.ac.uk/~aczc972

Thanks by the way! That was brilliant!

Comment: Your welcome, I can see an error on your page when clicking `home`
`Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #` (https://www.kevinleary.net/jquery-syntax-error-unrecognized-expression/) please verify if this is not causing the problem

Comment: Ok this comes from `$(targetHref).offset().top` you cannot get element like `$(#)`

Comment: Please update your snippet above so we can take a look on it

Comment: Hi! I have updated it so it has your code in it. Do I have to change the #?

Comment: The code you suggested seem to work in the sense that it doesnt disable the sticky header or remove the main slideshow, which happened before. However, it is still covering the content, so I assume I need to go in and manually change the offset positioning in the code?

Comment: Please remove `import jquery from "jquery";` and `const $ = jquery;`, I have use it because I imported it from `node_modules` (jquery can be injected then by any module bundler e.g. webpack - I belief they are using it on codesandbox - https://webpack.js.org/). You should put more attention in your console, so you can notice any error :) You already had jQuery on page so no need to use any bundlers

Comment: So, I might have solved it by adding -  180.
"scrollTop: $(targetHref).offset().top - 180"

I am updating the FTP so you can see. It is no longer hiding the content.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me! I only have two days left until I need to present my website, so it was causing significant stress. Now I just need to continue and fix my slick slider that isnt working. = )

Comment: Looks like `offset` returns object with `top` `left` (http://api.jquery.com/offset/ )properties so you had to subtract header height (If I am correct)

Comment: Yes, so first I tried to define a variable headerHeight = 180px, and take the top minus headerHeight, although it just disabled the whole functionality for the header and the slideshow. I just had to add - 180 to subtract the header height from the position.

Comment: Glad I could help, I have updated answer so it covers fully question. Could you please set is as answered if it helped you?

Answer (score 1):

You can also scroll to top of the page like:

Add `id="home"` to body and change href in:

`<li class="current"><a href="#">Home</a></li>`

to `home` i.e.

`<li class="current"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>`

Should work with your code

Answer (score 0):

This is not necessarily the best way to do this, but it's an example which is designed to illustrate how it can be done. You don't *need* jQuery to achieve this effect so it's worth trying it without.

The code below fixes the header, and adjusts the padding of the main wrapper to account for the size of the header. It then sets up listeners on elements with the class `section-link`. For those elements, the click event will scroll to the element with the id which corresponds to the `data-section` attribute for the element which was clicked.

You can ignore the css for this which was only added to illustrate how this might work.

```js
const padForHeader = () => {
  // find out how high the header element is
  const headerHeight = document.getElementById('top-header').clientHeight;

  // how much extra padding would we like?
  const headerPadding = 20;

  // add the two together to see how much padding we need to add
  const headerBufferSize = headerHeight + headerPadding;

  // set the marginTop property so that the header doesn't overlay content
  document.querySelector('.wrapper').style.marginTop = `${headerBufferSize}px`;
};

padForHeader();

// when the window resizes, re-pad for the header
window.addEventListener('resize', padForHeader);

document
  .querySelectorAll('.section-link')
  .forEach(element => {

    // we want to scroll 'smoothly' to the element
    const scrollOptions = {
      behavior: "smooth"
    };

    // we can read the data attribute to find the matching element's id
    const elementIdToScrollTo = element.dataset.section;

    // we can use the id we found to get the corresponding element
    const elementToScrollTo = document.getElementById(elementIdToScrollTo);

    // we can set the onclick property to scroll to the element we found
    element.onclick = () => elementToScrollTo.scrollIntoView(scrollOptions);
  });
```

```css
.header {
  background-color: red;
  border: solid 2px grey;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-family: arial;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 97%;
}

.header>ul {
  list-style: none;
  color: rgba(250, 250, 240, 0.8);
}

.header>ul>li {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  width: 200px;
}

.header>ul>li:hover {
  color: rgba(250, 250, 240, 1);
  top: -1px;
}

.section {
  background-color: rgba(20, 20, 30, 0.2);
  height: 80vh;
  border-bottom: solid 2px black;
  padding-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="top-header" class="header sticky">
    <ul>
      <li class="section-link" data-section="1">Item 1</li>
      <li class="section-link" data-section="2">Item 2</li>
      <li class="section-link" data-section="hello-world">Item hello world</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div id="1" class="section">
    Test 1
  </div>
  <div id="2" class="section">
    Test 2
  </div>
  <div id="hello-world" class="section">
    Test 3
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Looks like an alternative solution if this does not work!

Comment: @DanielleJ it may be that rewriting it this way would make things easier to work with - something to consider at least